# erro num exercício de conversor de real para dolar em python

Tags: python-3.x, float

Olá, eu to tentando fazer um conversor de real pra dolar e pra valores normais ele funciona mas fica dando erro quando ponho o dolar*n10, tipo 420 reais, ou 840, ele fica sobrando o valor exato do dolar exemplo :

Digite quantos reais você tem: 840

Digite a cotação atual do dolar: 4.20

Você com 840.00 reais pode comprar 199.00 dólares e te sobram 4.20 reais

Process finished with exit code 0

creio que é porque to usando float mas não sei como fazer de outro jeito, segue o código abaixo :

```
r = float(input('Digite quantos reais você tem: '))

d = float(input('Digite a cotação atual do dolar: '))

print('Você com {:.2f} reais pode comprar {:.2f} dólares e te sobram {:.2f} reais'.format(r, r // d, r % d))
```

Comment: Só tem sentido utilizar o operador resto da divisão para operandos inteiros. Você utilizou para operandos float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema não está na conversão numérica, mas no fato de que você está calculando a sobra como resto da divisão de real por dólar. O procedimento correto é subtrair da renda em real o valor do dólar convertido pela taxa de câmbio. Veja:

```
r = float(input('Digite quantos reais você tem: '))

d = float(input('Digite a cotação atual do dolar: '))

poder_compra = r//d
restante = r - (poder_compra*d)

print('Você com {:.2f} reais pode comprar {:.2f} dólares e te sobram {:.2f} reais'.format(r, poder_compra, restante))
```

Comment: Teve o problema de todas as contas darem resto 0, porém transformei poder_compra em int e deu tudo certo